# Limitar el campo de influencia de un título en el lenguaje de marcado Markdown

Tags: markdown

estoy documentando un proyecto personal y tengo una pequeña duda respecto a los **títulos** en el lenguaje **Markdown** con la cual quisiera que me ayuden por favor.

**La cuestión es la siguiente:**
Al introducir un título (h1,h2,h3 o cualquier otro), aparece en el costado izquierdo de este, una pequeña flecha que indica que se puede ocultar todo lo que haya debajo, el problema es que no sé cómo limitar el "campo de acción" de esta función, hace un tiempo probé con colocar `---` con lo cual se introduce una línea horizontal divisoria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como pueden ver en la imagen siguiente, esto no solucionó mi pequeño dilema, ya que la línea divisoria terminaba por ocultarse también

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La única manera que conozco hasta ahora para frenar la acción que hace esta flecha al costado izquierdo del título, es la de colocar otro título de igual o mayor tamaño debajo, es decir, si tengo un h1 coloco otro h1, si tengo un h3 coloco un h1, h2 o h3.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me gustaría saber si existe una manera de delimitar el texto que se oculta bajo mi título sin necesidad de tener que colocar otro título debajo.

Comment: El folding u ocultamiento no es un tema del lenguaje, en markdown solo defines los títulos y sus niveles, ese ocultamiento seguramente te lo brinda el editor que estás usando, comenta en todo caso con que editor estás trabajando, aunque generalmente son comportamientos que no suelen poder modificarse de forma sencilla.